# How to add specific blend mode to custom AccessoryView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i have a tableview and i wish to customize accessoryview button.
For that i have custom PNG image with semi-transparent pixels.

```
UIButton *myAccessoryButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
[myAccessoryButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[myAccessoryButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[myAccessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accessory_btn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myAccessoryButton addTarget: self
                      action: @selector(accessoryButtonTapped:withEvent:)
            forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell setAccessoryView:myAccessoryButton];
```

And that works fine for me button draws, except one trouble. In my template (PSD) this button has  blend mode - overlap, and when i export that button from PSD format it have white semi-transparent pixels which must blends with table background in same overlap blend-mode. But by default exported PNG blends in default mode when i load it as UIImage to customize my accessoryview.

How to change blend mode of UIImage or UIButton  or AccessoryView may be?

[image: it's photoshop view]
[image: it's simulator view]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to post pictures - both Photoshop showing how you want it to look, and from the app showing how it currently looks?  That said, you probably can't do what you want just by changing a view setting.  You _can_ access many useful compositing effects if you draw manually, using `CGBlendMode`.  So, you could create a `UIView` subclass, then in its `drawRect` method draw a portion of the table background, then draw the image on top with the blend mode you need.  It would be nice to skip the background drawing step, but you probably can't.

Comment: @dondragmer thank for your reply. I attach samples in main topic. Looks like youre right and only way to do what i want is to do what you suggest :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the picture on the left what you get in Photoshop?  You want it to brighten the background without altering its hue?  If so, there's no easy way to achieve that.

There are two partial solutions:

1. Have a single `drawRect` block (or its `CALayer` equivalent) which draws the background and the draws the glow using the appropriate `CGBlendMode`.
2. Edit the picture so the glow at the bottom is the shade of brown of your current background.

Either way, you lose flexibility; it would be nice to drag around your buttons or change the background graphic and have everything merge together nicely.

This may change.  `CALayer` already has a property called `compositingFilter`.  However, as of iOS 5.1, its behavior is undefined.  If anyone reads this in a future where iOS *does* have compositing filter that work, please add a comment to say so.

Comment: Thanx. Yes - left is photoshop picture. Right is simulator. 2nd variant is easyest but it dont looks like it must if i do so (change semi-transparen white to semi-transparent brown) however its really easyest way to do almost what i want. Very close in result.

Comment: To get what i want i do next change overlap blend mode to default. After change color from white to red-brown in that area and add some noice. now it looks very close to original in simulator (3rd picture)